# Validation not run when creating through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the two following models

Tournament

```
  has_many :signups, foreign_key: 'tournament_id', class_name: 'TournamentSignup', dependent: :destroy

def sign_up(team)
   #signups.create team: team #This does not work
   TournamentSignup.create tournament: self, team: team #This works
```

TournamentSignup

```
  belongs_to :tournament
  belongs_to :team, class_name: 'TournamentTeam', foreign_key: 'tournament_team_id'

  validates :team, presence: true
  validates :tournament, presence: true
```

Testcase that fails

```
it 'should not allow nil to sign up' do
team = nil
tournament = create(:tournament, type: 'Dota2Tournament')
tournament.sign_up team

signups = tournament.signups

expect(signups.size).to eq(0)
end
```

The validation is not runned when I use the first approach. Why is it so?
Using rails 4.0.2

Comment: Try: `self.signups.create team: team` instead. Also you need to have a presence validation in `Tournament `  for `TournamentSignup`.

Comment: prefixing self. did not change anything. validates :tournament_signup, presence: true like so? Why do I need that?